# Google Adsense on Laravel 5+

Tags: php, laravel, ads, adsense

I need to put google adsense banners over my laravel website.

**I tried adding this to app.blade.php:**

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

**And tried adding this inside my php pages:**

```
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5236216752808292",
enable_page_level_ads: true
});
</script>
```

But its not showing anything, I also tried adding script src inside my page together with push script and also nothing. Can someone help?

My console shows:

> Uncaught I The resource
>   https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190204/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds
>   from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate
>   `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: Does your browser's error console show anything?

Comment: i added it in my question take a look please

Comment: Do you have any ad slots on the page? They'd look like `<ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456" data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>`...

Comment: I dont, is that a exact code i need to put?

Comment: Well, you'll have to put your own IDs in... but yeah, you'll have to have an ad slot on the page. All you've done is load the JavaScript that *handles* ad slots, but if you don't have any to handle there won't be any ads... there should be a "getting started" adsense tutorial in Google's docs here.

Comment: ive added with my id but no luck

Comment: @Zli Please did you finally find the solution ? I urgently need it

Comment: Yes, well it's simple it works in a same way it would work on any other framework/language. Just paste the code in your header.blade.php or whatever and it will show up. If it's not showing it might be that your Google AdSense isn't activated.